# I want to retrieve the only address value from firebase database?

Tags: angularjs, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve the only address value from firebase database!

```
$scope.address = $firebaseArray(fireBaseData.refUser().child($scope.user_info.uid).child("address"));
console.log(address);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps if you can include the log output and values of the input parameters you're using.

It looks like you've missed the ID of the address.  That is, your code currently describes this path:

```
/users/$UID/address/
```

But you may want:

```
/users/$USER_ID/address/$ADDRESS_ID
```

Once you've got that you could use the `once()` function to retrieve a snapshot of that sub-tree and then query the values in it.

For example,

```
    fireBaseData.refUser()
    .child($scope.user_info.uid + '/address/')
    .child( ADDRESS_ID )
    .once('value')
    .then( 
      function(snapshot) {
        $scope.address = snapshot.val().address
      }
    );
```

If you don't know ADDRESS_ID and you're sure there will only ever be one entry for it under a specific UID, then you might consider not using the push() function to set a unique ID for it.  If you have to though, you could try pulling all the nodes beneath `users/$UID/address/` and drill down from there, like this:

```
    fireBaseData.refUser()
    .child($scope.user_info.uid + '/address/')
    .once('value')
    .then( 
      function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          var addressRecord = childSnapshot.val();
          $scope.address = addressRecord.address;
        });
      }
    );
```